# Why doesn't grep work if a file is not specified?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, grep

I have some problem with the Linux grep command, it don't work !!!

I am trying the following test on my Ubuntu system:

1. I have create the following folder: `/home/andrea/Scrivania/prova`
2. Inside this folder I have created a txt file named prova.txt and inside this file I have write the string `test` and I have save it
3. In the shell I have first access the folder `/home/andrea/Scrivania/prova` and so I have launched the grep command in the following way:

   ```
   ~/Scrivania/prova$ grep test
   ```

The problem is that the cursor continues to blink endlessly and cannot find NOTHING! Why? What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've not provided files for the grep command to scan

`grep "test" *`

or for recursive

`grep -r "test" *`

Answer (score 4):

Because grep searches standard input if no files are given. Try this.

```
grep test *
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not running the command you were looking for.

`grep test *` will look for `test` in all files in your current directory.

`grep test prova.txt` will look for `test` specifically in `prova.txt`

(`grep test` will `grep` the `test` string in `stdin`, and will not return until `EOF`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe in something to grep - you cant just call grep test without any other arguments as it is actually doing nothing. try `grep test *`

Another use for grep is to pipe in a command

e.g. This is my home directory:

```
drwx------+  3 oliver  staff    102 12 Nov 21:57 Desktop
drwx------+ 10 oliver  staff    340 17 Nov 18:34 Documents
drwx------+ 17 oliver  staff    578 20 Nov 18:57 Downloads
drwx------@ 12 oliver  staff    408 13 Nov 20:53 Dropbox
drwx------@ 52 oliver  staff   1768 11 Nov 12:05 Library
drwx------+  3 oliver  staff    102 12 Nov 21:57 Movies
drwx------+  5 oliver  staff    170 17 Nov 10:40 Music
drwx------+  3 oliver  staff    102 20 Nov 19:17 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  4 oliver  staff    136 12 Nov 21:57 Public
```

If i run

```
l | grep Do
```

I get the result

```
drwx------+ 10 oliver  staff    340 17 Nov 18:34 Documents
drwx------+ 17 oliver  staff    578 20 Nov 18:57 Downloads
```

remember to **pipe** the grep command

Comment: But she can do that and she did it. And of course it's doing something. It's grepping the standard input which can be actually quite useful to enter some patterns manually to test if they match. Press `^D` (Ctrl-d) on an empty line to end the standard input stream and grep.

Answer (score 0):

From grep man page:

> Grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files
>   are
>          named, or the file name - is given) for lines containing a match to the
>          given PATTERN.

If you don't provide file name(s) for it to use, it will try to read from stdin.

Try `grep test *`

Answer (score 0):

As per [**GNU Grep 3.0**](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html)

> A file named `-` stands for standard input. If no input is specified,
>   `grep` searches the working directory `.` if given a command-line
>   option specifying recursion; otherwise, grep searches standard input.

So for OP's command, without any additional specification, `grep` tries to search in standard input, which is not actually provided there.

A simple approach is `grep -r [pattern]`, as per the above, to specify **recursion** with `-r` and search in current directory and sub-directories.

Also note that wildcard **`*`** only includes files, **not directories**. If used, a prompt might be shown for hint:

> grep: [directory_name]: Is a directory